# Generating an MD5 from a downloaded file via HttpClient does not match original MD5

Tags: c#, hash, dotnet-httpclient

One of our internal/external services (B) is generating a URL with encrypted data in the query string; this is generated for another service (A). Service B handles the request of this url.

I'm finding that I cannot generate the same MD5 and do not understand why.

Here is the relevant code and where it lays in the entire flow.

**Service A**

- Stores binary data in SQL
- Generates an MD5 and passes this, along with other information, to service B in order to receive a link
- Link is then emailed out

**Service B (link generation)**

- Receives a request to generate a link
- stores the supplied MD5 and other information
- Generates an encrypted url and returns it to Service A

**Service B (respond to link request)**

- URL is decrypted
- Fetches stored information, including the MD5 passed in earlier
- Downloads a file from service A
- Uses the same MD5 algorithm as earlier to generate an MD5 for the download
- Compares this MD5 to the one passed in earlier
- **they do not match**

**MD5 Code**

Code to generate the MD5 looks like this (Service B):

```
public static string Generate(this MemoryStream stream)
{
    if (!stream.CanSeek || !stream.CanRead)
        throw new NotSupportedException("Stream must support seek and read to use MD5.Generate()");

    using (MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider())
    {
        stream.Position = 0;
        return BitConverter.ToString(md5.ComputeHash(stream)).Replace("-", string.Empty).ToLower();
    }
}
```

**Code downloading the file and comparing MD5**

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(dcBaseUrl);
    HttpResponseMessage result = client.GetAsync("USDC/Package/" + request.PackageID).Result;

    if (result.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK && result.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Distribution Center threw an exception when trying to download package");

    downloadResponse.Stream =   (MemoryStream)result.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result;
}

string fileMD5 = downloadResponse.Stream.Generate();

// This is ALWAYS false, getting different MD5 and do not know wht
if (!md5.Equals(fileMD5))
    throw new InvalidOperationException("md5 mismatch");
```

I suspect it is how I am downloading the file, though I have tried numerous ways to get the contents, including:

```
byte[] package = result.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result;
downloadResponse.Stream.Write(package, 0, package.Length);
string fileMD5 = downloadResponse.Stream.Generate();
```

**Update**

Saves the file to disk from both places. File is the same:

[image]

Comment: Two things: `byte[].Equals()` will always return false unless the two byte arrays are the exact same one, try using `SequenceEqual()`. Secondly, md5 is not considered secure at all, and should be generally avoided for new development - you should instead look at something like sha256

Comment: Have you compared the bytes in the file to see if it is actually the exact same file?

Comment: @willaien - md5.Equals is a string extension. And the strings being compared are totally different. As for security. This should be more than secure enough for the needs we have. We're also using it to make sure the file requested for download is still the same as the one when the link was generated.

Comment: @Magnus - Service A controls the DB and actual files. Service B has no access to the DB or files directly, so we're using the MD5 to make sure the file supplied in the download is the same one that was used when the link was generated - its possible that the file in Service A could be replaced and this should invalidate the url

Comment: @willaien Where in the code posted is the `byte[].Equals()` you referring to?

Comment: I mean for debug purposes, save the file to disk and compare it to the file in the db. Perhaps they are not the same.

Comment: In addition to willaien's comment, if at some point in the future, your requirements change such that you have to enable the Windows FIPS compliance bit, you will not be able to instantiate the MD5CryptoServiceProvider class (an Exception will be thrown). As he says you should use at least SHA256 (DoD/DHS are now requiring SHA512).

Comment: @Magnus - they're the same for sure. I have all the services running in debug.

Comment: So if the files 100% are identical, then there is something wrong with either of the MD5 generators.

Comment: @Kevin - noted. That being said, it would make no difference at the moment if i used MD5 or SHA512 - they would both generate different strings and i do not know why

Comment: @Magnus - agreed. I don't know what though. Its the same extension wrapped up in a NuGet we built and used in both projects.

Comment: Then I think you should check the files. Or the MD5 passed along has been  tampered with somehow.

Comment: @Magnus - file is identical; see update. Am now looking at the MD5 code.

Comment: Just because they have the same size does not necessarily mean they are the same. But try running the md5 hash on the file on disk and see if it matches any if your other two hashes.

Comment: @Magnus - I run the MD5 algorithm against both on disc and it matches. It's also a different MD5 from the 2 others. So feel my MD5 must be very wrong....

Comment: Having written a few different hashing methods I cannot get anything to match.

Comment: Simply the data provided to the two MD5 hash functions is different. It could be an encoding difference or the way the MD5 is handled in the DB. The chance that an MD5 implementation is flawed is essentially zero providing they come from a substantial source.

Comment: can you include the code for the class that represents `downloadResponse`? also the code for "Code downloading the file and comparing MD5" has errors and can't be compiled (the first error i saw was `downloadResponse.Stream =   MemoryStream)result.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result;` is missing a `(`, but there may be more) You really need to simplify your code and create a [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that recreates the problem that we could copy and paste and run.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain - DownloadResponse is a simple DTO - It has `MemoryStream` and `string` types for `Stream` and `Filename` respectively. Ref the `(` - simple typo.

Comment: Without a  [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) I don't think anyone will be able to explain why it is not working.